# Annotations using GOOGLE-MAP-SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am new to iOS and working on the GOOGLE-MAP-SDK. Everything is going very well, but I am not able to use the annotations in this case due to which I am not able to locate my positions which I fetched from the placeAPI of Google.

So kindly help me out with my errors.

**Code File**

```
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=30.7343000,76.7933000&radius=500&types=food&name&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCGeIN7gCxU8baq3e5eL0DU3_JHeWyKzic"];

     //Formulate the string as URL object.
     NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

     // Retrieve the results of the URL.
     dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
          NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);

}
```

Here is the code from which I will receive the data and want to display it on the Google map.  `NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);` is giving me the out put...

Comment: If you could post some code which shows where you expect to retrieve your positions then others can help further.

Comment: @DarrylBayliss ok i will update my code.....